# How to get aws ebs pricing programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

Is it possible to download aws ebs pricing programmatically?

I was able to get the entire AWS service index file downloaded, but I don't see Amazon EBS listed.

I downloaded the AmazonEC2 pricing information. It has PricePerUnit, meaning for the EC2 instance, but nothing that specifically shows PricePerUnit for just the EBS volume...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/using-ppslong.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure there is.

Look for `"productFamily" : "Storage",` in offer file:

https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/us-east-1/index.json

```
"HY3BZPP2B6K8MSJF" : {
      "sku" : "HY3BZPP2B6K8MSJF",
      "productFamily" : "Storage",
      "attributes" : {
        "servicecode" : "AmazonEC2",
        "location" : "US East (N. Virginia)",
        "locationType" : "AWS Region",
        "storageMedia" : "SSD-backed",
        "volumeType" : "General Purpose",
        "maxVolumeSize" : "16 TiB",
        "maxIopsvolume" : "10000",
        "maxIopsBurstPerformance" : "3000 for volumes <= 1 TiB",
        "maxThroughputvolume" : "160 MB/sec",
        "usagetype" : "EBS:VolumeUsage.gp2",
        "operation" : "",
        "servicename" : "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud"
      }
    },
```

From there grab `sku` code and search for it and you will see something like this:

```
 "HY3BZPP2B6K8MSJF" : {
        "HY3BZPP2B6K8MSJF.JRTCKXETXF" : {
          "offerTermCode" : "JRTCKXETXF",
          "sku" : "HY3BZPP2B6K8MSJF",
          "effectiveDate" : "2018-06-01T00:00:00Z",
          "priceDimensions" : {
            "HY3BZPP2B6K8MSJF.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7" : {
              "rateCode" : "HY3BZPP2B6K8MSJF.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7",
              "description" : "$0.10 per GB-month of General Purpose SSD (gp2) provisioned storage - US East (Northern Virginia)",
              "beginRange" : "0",
              "endRange" : "Inf",
              "unit" : "GB-Mo",
              "pricePerUnit" : {
                "USD" : "0.1000000000"
              },
              "appliesTo" : [ ]
            }
          },
          "termAttributes" : { }
        }
      },
```