# How to get EBS pricing and disk info of AWS virtual machine (EC2)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I am using AWS SDK in order to get a list of their EC2 virtual machines that I store in a local database. In that database, I also store the disks info.

The virtual machines have different possible values : "EBS Only", "NA" and a "regular" disk (such as 1 x 800 NVMe SSD, which I assume is in GiB ?).

I did the same thing for Azure and their managed disks, and I wonder if it is possible to get some specific info about Amazon virtual machines' disks. For Azure I have :

```
public class AzureManagedDisk
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double IOPS { get; set; }
    public string Redundancy { get; set; }
    public double Size { get; set; }
    public double Speed { get; set; }
}
```

But for Amazon, with the "regular" disks (1 x 800 NVMe SSD), I can only get the disk size. Is there a way to get more info on that disk ?
With the "EBS Only", I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386296/how-to-get-aws-ebs-pricing-programmatically) but when I look in the JSON response I get, there is no such thing that describes the disk. I tried making a request using the VM sku, but indeed I get the virtual machine and not the EBS storage. Then, I looked to the different service codes, but I didn't see a code that could be used to retreive EBS offers (as I use "AmazonEC2" to fetch virtual machines), have I miss something in the codes ?

Comment: One option is to download it from: https://ec2instances.info/

Answer (score 0):

You may use this AWS CLI command.

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-types
```

If EC2 instance type supports InstanceStorage, then you can see details about local NVMe disks

```
    "InstanceStorageSupported": true,
    "InstanceStorageInfo": {
        "TotalSizeInGB": 2850,
        "Disks": [
            {
                "SizeInGB": 1425,
                "Count": 2,
                "Type": "ssd"
            }
        ],
```

For all current generation instance types, you may see EBS details. Note those define properties of the EC2 instance itself and not individual EBS volumes you may attach to the instance.

```
    "EbsInfo": {
        "EbsOptimizedSupport": "default",
        "EncryptionSupport": "supported",
        "EbsOptimizedInfo": {
            "BaselineBandwidthInMbps": 14250,
            "BaselineThroughputInMBps": 1781.25,
            "BaselineIops": 50000,
            "MaximumBandwidthInMbps": 14250,
            "MaximumThroughputInMBps": 1781.25,
            "MaximumIops": 50000
        },
        "NvmeSupport": "required"
    },
```

You may use this command

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes
```

to get info about individual volumes similar to your Azure managed disks example.

```
    "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1d",
    "CreateTime": "2022-07-18T19:06:34.922000+00:00",
    "Encrypted": false,
    "Size": 110,
    "SnapshotId": "",
    "State": "in-use",
    "VolumeId": "vol-05e8c4c8b76fd081a",
    "Iops": 3000,
    "VolumeType": "gp3",
    "MultiAttachEnabled": false,
    "Throughput": 750
```